# How to show {n:U(n,x) is defined for all x} is not enumerable

Tags: computability, undecidability

U(n,x) is Gödel universal function, and we need to show {n:U(n,x) is defined for all x} is not enumerable. I do not have any clue right now. Anyone can give me some hint about this question.

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.

Comment: Hint: Rice's theorem.

Comment: I still can not get it...

Comment: Dupe: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/24749/   related:  http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/43185/